# Why only the last row gets highlighted when I click the other rows in a Listview generated using SimpleAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, simpleadapter

I have generated a swiping `ListView` using a `SimpleAdapter` ( I have used the  `com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView` to generate the `ListView` ). I have done the following in it. When i swipe the `ListView` the front layout gets highlighted as Black and the color of a ImageView changes to Orange. It works fine when I have only one row in the ListView. But I noticed that when there are more than one row, whichever row is clicked the lastrow gets highlighted to Black. Can anyone tell me step by step how to fix this. I want to proceed with `SimpleAdapter` itself,but any other solutions are also welcomed. My codes are as below.Please go through it.

```
 public class mycontacts extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycontacts_activity, container,
            false);
    final SwipeListView swipy=(SwipeListView)view.findViewById(R.id.swipy);
    SimpleAdapter k=new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),val,R.layout.contact2,new String[]{"name","path","id"},new int[]{R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path,R.id.contactid})
    {
            @Override
            public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            { 
              final RelativeLayout l=(RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.front);
              swipy.setSwipeListViewListener(new BaseSwipeListViewListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClickFrontView(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onClickFrontView(position);
        l.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

}

    @Override
     public void onStartOpen(int position, int action, boolean right) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartOpen(position, action, right);
             }


      });
      return v;
            }
    };

    swipy.setAdapter(k);


    return view;

       }
```

contact2.xml file

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/back"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:tag="back" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="68dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@color/purple"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
</LinearLayout>

     <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/front"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:tag="front" >
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/example_itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/path"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/example_image"
        android:text="hiii"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/path"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/example_itemname"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="path"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contactid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/example_image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Id"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>

 </FrameLayout>
```

mycontacts_activity.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:id="@+id/mycontacts_id"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        android:id="@+id/swipy"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
        swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"


        swipe:swipeMode="right"
        />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: R.id.example_itemname,R.id.path,R.id.contactid.... of course all these are in same xml ..right?

Comment: Yes all are in the same xml files

Comment: then, they are not present here at what you have posted in xml..?

Comment: Can you post `mycontacts_activity.xml`?

Comment: and what about `R.id.path` & `R.id.contactid`? I can't find these elements?

Comment: I will post the full code

Comment: Can anyone guide me please?